# Generate pdf format and append data

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I want to able to generate an Attendance sheet from the android application. The attendance sheet format is like the picture below. i am fetching the data (example 50200) from a firebase database. there are more data same like this (50200) one which i need to append in the rest of the boxes.

[image: This is how my Attendance sheet should look like]

This is how i am fetching data from firebase which are StudentIds. I just want to write these student ids on by one in these format into the pdf.

```
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                RVStudent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                EmptyViewStudent.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                int i = 1;
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.child(userID).child("Course").child(CourseCode).child("Students").getChildren()) {
                    studentId[i]= dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                    studentName[i]=dataSnapshot.child(userID).child("Course").child(CourseCode).child("Students").child(studentId[i]).child("StudentName").getValue(String.class);
                    studentserial[i]= String.valueOf(i);

                    listStudent.add(new StudentModel(studentId[i],studentName[i], studentserial[i],CourseCode,CourseName, UserProfileImageUrl));
                    i++;
                }

                if(listStudent.size()==0){
                    RVStudent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    EmptyViewStudent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }


            }else{
                RVStudent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                EmptyViewStudent.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
```

i tried my RecyclerView it kind of worked but did not provide desired result and the pdf looks weird in someway as it is kind of screenshot of the RecyclerView. besides the pdf view varies device to device when use RecyclerView to generate it. Wht is the properway to do so.

Comment: not very clear what you want to say. but if you just want generate a pdf from your android phone, base way to user android native classes. see this example.        https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument

Comment: i edited my question. does it make sense now?

Comment: so again. my question is do you want to generate pdf of what you see in recycler view. is that right?

Comment: no.. i all ready tried that and the result is not like the image i attached. It gets burry or streched i just want to generate a pdf like the image. and append all the the number (Student Ids) inside the boxes like the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution after reading the document of ITEXT. Though i don't know is it the optimal way to do it or not but it worked for me perfectly.

```
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String studentId[] = new String[50];

            listStudentId.clear();
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
             //   EmptyViewStudent.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                int i = 1;
                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1 : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    studentId[i]= dataSnapshot1.getKey();
                    listStudentId.add(new StudentIdModel(studentId[i]));
                    i++;
                }

                if(listStudentId.size()==0){

                }
            }else{

            }

            try {
                Document document = new Document();
                File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "/sams_images/AttendanceSheet");
                root.mkdir();
                String sdcardhtmlpath = root.getPath().toString() + "/"+CourseCode+ ".pdf";
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(sdcardhtmlpath));

                document.open();
                PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
                ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
                ct.setSimpleColumn(200,750,400,780);
                String documentTitle = CourseCode + " " + CourseName;
                Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(new Phrase(2,documentTitle, FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES_BOLD, 15)));//add ur string here
                ct.addElement(paragraph);
                ct.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
                ct.go();

                writeData(writer, document);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("PDFcreation", e.toString());
            }

        }
```

then i implemented a loop which will create every set of view one by one..

```
public void writeData(PdfWriter writer, Document document) throws DocumentException {

    int lrectllx = 70;
    int lrectlly = 720;
    int lrecturx = 280;
    int lrectury = 750;

    int rrectllx = 320;
    int rrectlly = 720;
    int rrecturx = 530;
    int rrectury = 750;

    String StudentId[] = new String[50];

    double cr= 9.50;

    for(int i=0; i<listStudentId.size(); i++){

        /* if dataIndex [i] is even number will create box at left side and for odd number create box at right side*/

        if (i%2 == 0){
            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();
            /*-------------------------- Creating circle -------------------------------------*/
            canvas.circle(lrecturx- 30, (lrectlly+lrectury)/2, cr);
            canvas.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);

            /*-------------------------- Creating Rectangle -------------------------------------*/
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(lrectllx, lrectlly, lrecturx, lrectury);
            rectangle.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
            canvas.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
            rectangle.setBorderWidth(1);
            canvas.rectangle(rectangle);

            /*--------------------------- Appending Text -------------------------------------*/
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
            ct.setSimpleColumn(rectangle);
            StudentId[i] = listStudentId.get(i).getStudentId();
            Paragraph studentid = new Paragraph(new Phrase(20,StudentId[i], FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 15)));//add ur string here
            studentid.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            studentid.setIndentationLeft(20);
            ct.addElement(studentid);
            ct.go();

            lrectlly = lrectlly - 42;
            lrectury = lrectury - 42;
           // lcx = lrecturx- 30 ;
           // lcy = (lrectlly+lrectury)/2;

        }else{
            PdfContentByte canvas = writer.getDirectContent();

            /*-------------------------- Creating circle -------------------------------------*/
            canvas.circle(rrecturx- 30, (rrectlly+rrectury)/2, cr);
            canvas.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);

            /*-------------------------- Creating Rectangle -------------------------------------*/
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(rrectllx, rrectlly, rrecturx, rrectury);
            rectangle.setBorder(Rectangle.BOX);
            rectangle.setBorderWidth(1);
            canvas.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLACK);
            canvas.rectangle(rectangle);

            /*-------------------------- Appending Text ---------------------------------------*/
            ColumnText ct = new ColumnText(canvas);
            ct.setSimpleColumn(rectangle);
            StudentId[i] = listStudentId.get(i).getStudentId();
            Paragraph studentid = new Paragraph(new Phrase(20,StudentId[i], FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.TIMES, 15)));//add ur string here
            studentid.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
            studentid.setIndentationLeft(20);
            ct.addElement(studentid);
            ct.go();

            rrectlly = rrectlly - 42;
            rrectury = rrectury - 42;
        //    rcx = rrecturx- 30 ;
        //    rcy = (rrectlly+rrectury)/2;
        }
    }

    document.close();

}
```

finally this is the pdf file i got..

[image: I did not have to sacrifice anything. As with RecyclerView there is always concern about the quality and how different mobile devices will capture different type of view according to the view attributes.]

I am sure it will help number of people who are trying to format pdf file from android device or using other language for creating pdf file with specific formats. Regards.. everyone.